# ¿Cómo usar alias para no mencionar los nombres de columnas en MySQL?

Tags: php, mysql, insert

Como hacer una sentencia de INSERT INTO donde los campos no sean mencionados, o sea colocar un alias... Yo obtengo los campos con esta función...

```
 function obtener_campos($schema,$tabla) {
        $sql="select column_name as x
            from information_schema.columns 
            where table_schema = '$schema'
            and table_name = '$tabla'";
        mysql_select_db($schema,$GLOBALS["conn"]);
        if ($z=mysql_query($sql,$GLOBALS["conn"])) {
            while($q=mysql_fetch_array($z)){
                if($q["x"]!='id'){
                    $campos[]=$q["x"];
                }
            }
            return $campos; 
        }
    }
```

Eso lo utilizo para subir plantillas de prueba en excel a un servicio, pero quiero que al momento de llenar esas planillas no sean con el nombre de los campos sino con alias, para darle mas seguridad a la tabla...

[image: ejemplo de la plantilla de excel]

Comment: No te hagas *ilusiones* sobre la seguridad. Lo que tú intentas hacer (no me consta que se pueda), no aporta absolutamente **nada** a la seguridad. Una consulta de inserción no tiene por qué mostrarse... **¿no te referirás a las columnas del `SELECT`** (en ese caso sí puedes usar alias)?. Los errores de seguridad **graves** los tienes aquí: `where table_schema = '$schema'` y aquí: `and table_name = '$tabla'`. Ahí tienes un grave riesgo de inyección, si alguien cambia el valor de `$schema` o de `$tabla` por código malicioso. Eso es lo que debes corregir.

Comment: Si las columnas de la planilla están en el mismo orden que los campos de la tabla, sólo no pongas los campos explícitos en la sentencia de inserción. Como la planilla no tiene el campo ID, y asumo que este campo es autoincremental, le pasas null al primer elemento del array a insertar

Comment: Pero es que yo no entiendo. **¿Tú insertas la SQL de inserción en la hoja de Excel o muestras en la hoja el resultado del `SELECT`?** Son dos cosas totalmente distintas. Supongo que lo que **muestras** en el excel es el resultado del `SELECT col1, col2...`. En ese caso sí puedes usar alias: `SELECT col1 as aliascol1, col2 as aliascol2...` en ese caso los datos vendrán con los nombres de columna `aliascol1, aliascol2...`

Comment: No la SQL de inserción esta en el codigo. Lo que yo inserto en la hoja de excel es los valores de cada campo

Comment: A eso me refiero, la SQL de inserción **el usuario nunca la ve**, por lo que no veo el sentido de cambiar los nombres de columnas en ella. Donde sí puedes cambiar los nombres de columna es el en `SELECT`, como ya he explicado en el anterior comentario. Entonces, en el Excel, el usuario verá `aliasX`, `aliaY`, `aliasLoQueSea` en vez de los nombres reales. No sé si me entiendes lo que quiero decir...